# Poetry refuses to install wheel file while pip installs

Tags: python, pip, python-poetry

I'm trying to install local wheel file using Poetry v 1.5.1 by adding the following line to pyproject.toml in [tool.poetry.dependencies] section:

```
my_package = {file  = "/home/user/package.whl"}
```

and it ends up with the following error:

```
Because my_package (0.1.0) @ file:///home/user/package.whl depends on shapely (>=2.0.1,<3.0.0) which doesn't match any versions, my_package is forbidden.
```

If to run

```
poetry add shapelly==2.0.1
```

It works well.
If to re-create environment it starts to complain on another package (not shapely) in the same fashon. And finally,

```
pip install /home/user/package.whl
```

works well without any problems.

What is wrong with Poetry here?